# Deep cloning using MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is it possible to deep clone an object using MongoDB? in C# like:

```
Object1 _object2 = new Object1();

BsonValue _bsonValue = _object2.ToBsonDocument().DeepClone()

//now _bsonValue to "Object1" - how to?
```

How do I convert a "_bsonValue" back to "Object1" class? This is not really for saving object to MongoDB, just deep cloning an object and using the object elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert _bsonValue back to an BsonDocument with ToBsonDocument() and then it's up to you to convert from that back to your class.